# Custom context menu connecting in Qt

Tags: qt, contextmenu

I have a problem with connecting custom menu in `QListWidget`, the connect function returns false. Here is the code:

I've got some main window class called `MainWindow`. In its constructor I have this line

```
connect(ui->notesWidget, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint &)), 
        this, SLOT(contextMenuforNotesArea(QPoint &)));
```

where `notesWidget` is mentioned `QListWidget`.

`ContextMenuforNotesArea(QPoint &)` is defined like this

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
public slots:
    void contextMenuforNotesArea(QPoint &pos);
};

void MainWindow::contextMenuforNotesArea(const QPoint &pos){
    QMessageBox::information(this, "a", "the function has been finally called");
    QMenu contextMenu(tr("Context menu"), this);
    contextMenu.addAction(new QAction(tr("Hello"), this));
    contextMenu.exec(mapToGlobal(pos));
}
```

I have also changed the property `contextMenu` in the `listWidget` to `customContextMenu` through form designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your SLOT signature as follows in the header file

```
void contextMenuforNotesArea(const QPoint &pos);
```

Also make sure, when you are doing the connection in the constructor, you do it after the calling of `setupUi`

Comment: yeah, thanks now it works, just the menu is created a bit above the mouse, this is the function void MainWindow::contextMenuforNotesArea(const QPoint &pos){ QMenu contextMenu(tr("Context menu"), this); contextMenu.addAction(new QAction(tr("Hello"), this)); contextMenu.exec(mapToGlobal(pos)); }
sorry about the mess, but Im new here and dont know why the code didnt appeared as a code, I have written 4 spaces before the lines :/

Comment: you need to call the respective widget's `mapToGlobal(const QPoint & pos)` method, in this case `contextMenu.exec(mapToGlobal(pos))` should be changed as `contextMenu.exec(ui->notesWidget->mapToGlobal(pos))`, check if that works